# When exporting Gmail contacts, the names not showing

Tags: gmail, google-contacts, export

In Gmail, I have a large Group that I use for communications. I downloaded the group to Excel using the Export option and created a csv file.

While everyone on my list has a first and last name. A good number of these fields are blank on the export. When I look at the record it looks exactly the same as one where the first and last name did export.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that when importing into Excel some of that information is being misplaced or lost.
Try to change the separator. Maybe some fields have the separator within, therefore confusing the importer.
Also, try to import section by section.

Answer (score 0):

Finally a resolution...in the actual contact, you need to add them to a Google+ Circle.  Once you add them, the first and last names should export into a csv.